# Turning byte array back into img

Tags: c#

```
public byte[] ImageToByte(string imgUrl)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = client.DownloadData(imgUrl);
        return imageBytes;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So i've used this piece of code to download images as bitarrays and I have added them to a database.
I wanna know how I can turn the byte array back into an image.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this :

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks quick question, when i have that imageobjekt, how can i show it on my html page?

Comment: Generally, we do not prefer to save the img file as an array in web applications.
Instead, we keep the img file in a folder on the server.We keep the path of this img file in the database.When we want to show the img file, it is enough to know its path.